# Function inside JavaScript Array map not returning promises

Tags: javascript, promise

Trying to process all results of an array `nodes` from a function but nothing was added to `promises`.

```
const promises = nodes.map(localModelScan);

function localModelScan(node) {
    let text = node.textContent;
    model.then(function (res) {
        if(res.check(node.text) > 0.3) return node;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Add `return model` at the end of the localModelScan

Comment: `localModelScan()` has no return value.  The `return node` you have is inside a nested function, not the return value from `localModelScan()`.

Comment: specify what happens on the `else` branch of the `if` statement otherwise your Promises will resolve `undefined`. do not `.catch` errors in `loadModelScan`, instead allow the error to bubble up and have the caller decide what to do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `return model;` at the end of your `localModelScan` function, otherwise `promises` will just be an array full of `undefined`.

```js
const promises = nodes.map(localModelScan);

function localModelScan(node) {
    let text = node.textContent;
    return model.then(function (res) {
        if(res.check(node.text) > 0.3) return node;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can write this as an arrow function:

```js
const localModelScan = (node) => model.then((res) => {
        if(res.check(node.text) > 0.3) return node;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });

const promises = nodes.map(localModelScan);
```

Comment: @jfriend00 I forgor 